# How to update values in nested list?

Tags: python

Now I have a nested list with integers and the amout of layers is uncertain based on user input.
How can I go though each element and update its value?

For example, use char() for conversion.

```
Input[1]: l = [1, 2, 3]
Output[1]: l = ['\x01', '\x02', '\x03']

Input[2]: l = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
Output[2]: l = ['\x01', '\x02', '\x03', ['\x04', '\x05', '\x06']]

Input[3]: l = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9]]]
Output[3]: l = ['\x01', '\x02', '\x03', ['\x04', '\x05', '\x06', ['\x07', '\x08', '\t']]]
```

I can do recursive.

```
def convert(l):
  for i, e in enumerate(l):
    if isinstance(e, list):
      convert(e)
    else:
      l[i] = chr(e)
```

But if there is a more elegant way? I've tried to use `yield` to get all values but have no idea how to put it back to the list.

```
def get_all_values(l):
  for e in l:
    if isinstance(e, list):
      yield from get_all_values(e)
    else:
      yield e

def convert(l):
  for e in get_all_values(l):
    print(chr(e))  # Don't know how to put it back to list.
```

Comment: recursive approach makes more sense here. Lists are mutable, i.e. can be changed inplace. Generators (yield-ing functions) will require to construct a new nested list, which is a lot more expensive. Same applies to list comprehensios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to do this without mutating the original list is to use recursion and a list comp:

```
def convert(l):
    return [convert(e) if isinstance(e, list) else chr(e) for e in l]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a beautiful solution and won't affect the original list.

Answer (score 0):

You're close! Since you're getting each value from `get_all_values` you can collect them as they're yielded using a list generator like so:

```py
def convert(l):
    converted = [chr(e) for e in get_all_values(l)]
    return converted
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to put yielded values into a list you simply surround it with brackets.

```py
def get_all_values(l):
  for e in l:
    if instance(e, list):
      yield from get_all_values(e)
    else:
      yield e

def convert(l):
  print ([chr(e) for e in get_all_values(l)])
```

The example also has list comprehension.

Just doing `[get_all_values(l)]` puts it in a list

Comment: `[get_all_values(l)]` will put an unrealized generator in a list - not what OP wants.

Comment: it's not what needs to be used in this specific problem but OP wanted to know how to put generators in lists and it's useful information

Comment: you think giving OP something that looks like `[<generator object get_all_values at 0x7fe2ac08e050>]` is useful? agree to disagree. i think what you want to do is `list(get_all_values(l)` as this will realize the generator.